# Exchange Server 2007 Add Email address to public folder

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

I am able to create a public folder via exchange 2007 admin > tool. How or where do I go to add an email address to the public folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997560(EXCHG.80).aspx